# Crossbar.io pass RPC arguments to dynamic authorizer

Tags: authorization, rpc, crossbar

I am using Crossbars dynamic authorization to authorize all RPCs in my application.

Is it or will it be possible to access the arguments of the RPC in the authorizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible to solve the issue by utilizing "pattern based registrations". The argument can then be moved into the URI to be examined by the authorizer.

For example the protected resource can register **com.example.user.*.delete** and when the procedure is called with **com.example.user.123.delete** - the authorizer will be able to extract the user ID from the URI.

This is documented in the WAMP spec and also in the documentation for Crossbar.io

Comment: @ronalchn: It does seem to answer the question. It gives the keywords to use for the general approach in (hopefully) enough detail to allow the final solution to be worked out from there.

Comment: This worked for me in the end, the callee can access the URI like so:  `session.register('com.example.user.*.delete', function(args, kwargs, details) { 
    var id = details.procedure.split('.')[2]; 
  }, {    
    match: 'wildcard'
  }));`

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the arguments of the RPC is not possible. Dynamic authorization is there to work on the level of the data contained in the configuration, not application payload. If you want to do authorization based on the payload, then this needs to be triggered from the side of the callee.